# Regular Expression OR

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to write an regular expression and I need your help...

**Requirement** - 
first character is "*s*", then it must be followed by two numeric digits Eg - S98
If it is not "*s*", then it must be followed by two alphabet characters *{A-Z, a-z}*, Eg -aIO

I have written as like before and it **not working**. It is working if I divide into two parts separately(before and after |),but not together..

`regexevent = /^([s]{1})([0-9]{2})| ([a-rt-z]{1})([A-Za-z]{2})$/;`

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` and `^` are part of the OR, so it's looking for the LHS start anchored or RHS end anchored. You need to wrap the whole thing in parenthesis...

```
regexevent = /^(([s]{1})([0-9]{2})| ([a-rt-z]{1})([A-Za-z]{2}))$/;
```

Alternatively, you could write your regex a bit terser...

```
regexevent = /^(s\d{2}|[a-rt-z][A-Za-z]{2})$/;
```

(Assuming some of those capturing groups aren't required.)

Also...

> first character is "s", then it must be followed by two numeric digits Eg - S98

Your regex will fail if it's a `S` (you only check for `s`). You could use `[sS]`.

Comment: Thanks you Alex.. `regexevent = /^(s\d{2}|[a-rt-z][A-Za-z]{2})$/;` It is working fine...